# Create a file in Github Repository using their API using R

Tags: r, github, github-api

I would like to create a file in a Github repository using the PUT request to the Github API, more info here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file

This is the code I use to authenticate (you need to change your app and secret numbers):

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)

# 1. Find OAuth settings for github:
#    http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/
oauth_endpoints("github")

# 2. Register an application at https://github.com/settings/applications
#    Insert your values below - if secret is omitted, it will look it up in
#    the GITHUB_CONSUMER_SECRET environmental variable.
#
#    Use http://localhost:1410 as the callback url
myapp <- oauth_app("TestApp", "app-number","secret-number")
scope <- 'public_repo'
# 3. Get OAuth credentials
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"),scope=scope, myapp)
```

My Github username is `aruizga7` and the repository name is `-repoName-`. The code I use to do the PUT request to the Github API is:

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/aruizga7/-repoName-/contents/path"
data = list("message"=("my commit message"),
            "content"=  upload_file(("C:/example.txt")))
r<-PUT(url,body = data,config(token = github_token),encode = "json")
content(r)
```

The result of this request is the following:

```
$message
[1] "Invalid request.\n\n[\"my commit message\"] is not a string.\n\"content\" wasn't supplied."

$documentation_url
[1] "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/"
```

Anyone can help on this?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this different from your previous questions on the topic?

Comment: The other question was about how to create the repository using the POST request, and that worked fine. This is about how to push files using PUT request, connected but different things

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but there's a couple of things I can call out: a) `/path` on the end should be the relative path to the file in your repository, b) `message` seems to be encoded as an array, rather than a literal string, and c) `content` should be the base64-encoded file - I don't think `upload_file` is the right behaviour here.